# make sybase bcp fast on a remote machine

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase, bcp

Is there a way to use bcp out or select query to get data faster from a DB on a remote server (Sybase ASE)?

Does bcp out provide any data compression options? I have to download `12GB` of data from a table and I am getting speed of *4Mbps over the network*, so it takes lot of time to unload all the data.

One way could be to run the bcp out on the same machine on which DB is hosted and compress the file and then send it over the network, but I do not have permissions to run bcp/select directly on the remote machine.

Does Sybase ASE provide any means unload data in compressed form?

Answer (score 0):

BCP does not have any compression option.  Over the network, the best you can do is chosing `native` mode instead of `character` mode, as it is slightly more efficient. In my environment I get around 10% less disk space used when using native BCP.

Your suggestion of BCP out on the local server, then doing compress & transfer is likely going to be faster than BCP over the network.  In my environment, we do that regularly.

Another alternative would be use Componenet Integration Services (CIS) to 'mount' the remote database to your local machine, and extract the data that way, as long as you have select permissions in the remote database.  I do not know how this will compare regarding speed.

[SAP Sybase ASE: CIS documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32702.1550/html/omni_ug/title.htm):